# Building Docker images on a system with no root access

Tags: docker, dockerfile, opensuse

I'm trying to build a `Dockerfile` into an image. I would like to use a system running OpenSUSE that is fairly locked down -- I have no root access and so can't install docker or run a docker daemon to use the usual `docker build` method.

I have looked into various ways of doing this but they all seem to require root access at one point despite claiming to run as unprivileged.

[img](https://github.com/genuinetools/img) seemed promising, but running the binary results in the error `failed to use newuidmap` and fixing this seems to require modifying a root-owned file.

[Buildah](https://github.com/containers/buildah) also seemed promising, but I run into similar uid issues that require root to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can build container images using buildah without root access. In order to do that, you need to [set up UID mapping](https://github.com/containers/buildah/blob/2dc96b2276faf0847c9a38438cf1e5901e76f7fc/docs/buildah-unshare.md), which requires root access - editing `/etc/subuid`:

```
$ cat /etc/subuid
username:100000:65536
$ ll /etc/subuid
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 34 Dec  3 14:17 /etc/subuid
```

Unless your distribution provides `/etc/subuid` pre-filled, which works with your unprivileged user, there is nothing you can do given the current linux kernel implementation (<4.20).

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking about run Docker with using root Or sudo you can use this.

Type:

```
 $ sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker
```

Hit Enter then type:

```
$ newgrp docker
```

Now run docker with using root

Comment: I don't have root access

Comment: This method won't, but I'm asking if there is any method to build an image without root acccess.